# How to find distinct element on the basis of a particular column from JavaRDD<ObjectHandler> object?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, distinct-values

My JavaRDD structure looks like this  :-

```
[
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:48:10.108Z],
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:51:12.089Z], 
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:52:44.285Z],
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:54:23.250Z],
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:55:35.045Z],
ObjectHandler [username=Hello, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T10:40:07.929Z], 
ObjectHandler [username=Hello, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T10:40:54.602Z],
ObjectHandler [username=neelam, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-03T07:16:23.085Z]
]
```

Now i want distinct element on username like this:-

```
[
ObjectHandler [username=KAJAL, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T06:48:10.108Z],
ObjectHandler [username=Hello, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-02T10:40:54.602Z],
ObjectHandler [username=neelam, properties={}, event_name=INSTALL, pname=null, ptype=null, pvalue=null, date=2016-08-03T07:16:23.085Z]
]
```

I have used `JavaRDD.distinct()` function but result was same.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaRDD.distinct()` would invoke `ObjectHandler.equals` to check for distinctness - if you haven't overridden it, each `ObjectHandler` would be considered different and thus you'd end up with the same RDD.

You have therefore two options:

1. **Override `equals` and `hashCode`, only compare `username`**: this is simple to do, and then `distinct` would return the expected result. The downside is - you might want two instances of `ObjectHandler` to be considered *different* even if they have the same `username` under some other circumstances. In other words, other use cases in your program would require stricter equality of these objects. If that's the case, you can use the second approach:
2. **Reduce by `username`**: extract the `username` into the RDD's "key", reduce by that key while "randomly" choosing one of the matching values, and then get rid of these keys. With Java 8 this would look like:

   ```
   final JavaRDD<ObjectHandler> result = rdd
       .keyBy(v -> v.username)
       .reduceByKey((ObjectHandler v1, ObjectHandler v2) -> v1)
       .values();
   ```

   with Java 7 this would look a bit messy, but the logic is identical:

   ```
   final JavaRDD<ObjectHandler> result = rdd.keyBy(new Function<ObjectHandler, String>() {
       @Override
       public String call(ObjectHandler v1) throws Exception {
           return v1.username;
       }
   }).reduceByKey(new Function2<ObjectHandler, ObjectHandler, ObjectHandler>() {
       @Override
       public ObjectHandler call(ObjectHandler v1, ObjectHandler v2) throws Exception {
           return v1; // choosing one "randomly"
       }
   }).values();
   ```

Comment: @ Tzach Zohar - Thank you :)